# Rails: Is it possible to initialize some stuff in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, redis

In one of the my initializer I need to fetch some hashes from a redis instance.
However due to the number of hashs and the connection weaknesses the loading can take quite a moment.
Since it's in the initializer, the application is not available until the hashes have all been loaded.

Therefore I was thinking I could perform the initialization in a thread so the application can start and then the hashes would get loaded on their on time as they are not essential to the application.

I have tried something like this:

```
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
STORE = {}
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
Thread.new do
  REDIS.keys.each do |key|
    STORE[key] = REDIS[key]
  end
end
```

But it does not work and there are no error messages :(

Any ideas?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you please explain a bit more?

- What is the goal here? What are you doing with the contents of the hashes?
- What stack are you running?

I tried a simple test against Rails 3.0.5/WEBrick running on my local machine (OS X 10.6.7):

```
puts "I am in the main thread."
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
Thread.new do
  for i in 1..5
    puts "I am in a thread."
    sleep 2
  end
end
Thread.new do
  for i in 1..5
    puts "I am in another thread."
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

And it worked the way I expected:

```
ultramarine:ThreadTest jdc$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
I am in the main thread.
I am in a thread.
I am in another thread.
[2011-03-23 18:30:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-03-23 18:30:28] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-12-25) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
[2011-03-23 18:30:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5802 port=3000
I am in another thread.
I am in a thread.
I am in another thread.
I am in another thread.
I am in a thread.
I am in another thread.
I am in a thread.
I am in a thread.
```

Comment: I am running rails 3.0.3, and I am trying to load the hashes from REDIS into a local hash contained in memory of the application to store some I18n translation for the internationalization. I created a /config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb and tried to add the thread in there. But as soon as the "Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)" is loaded, it seems that the thread just stops.

Comment: Well actually it works :) but not in console mode. Bu when launching the server it works just fine, I just did not try since I did not see it working in console... thanks !

Comment: well... I take it back, it works in development environment, but not it production mode :( The hashes never get loaded in prod mode

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about your production stack?

Comment: Rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.8.7. It seems that in server production mode the threads crashes when accessing REDIS, but in dev, staging and test tests it works fine. That really weird because it's always the same REDIS instance I am trying to access. When I am able to reproduce the issues it give me an error: threaderror stopping only thread